# Plotting a surface in Python from three measurment arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis, mplot3d

Hello I have three arrays x, y, and z where i want to view the, magnitude of variable z at the co-ords of x and y. I.e. I want to plot a surface of three [6147,1] arrays. using the code below i get Value Error: cannot reshape array of size 6147 into shape (6147,6147) can anyone trouble shoot this and help me get this visualisation to work?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_frame = pd.read_excel (r'\Users\alexd\OneDrive\Documents\University\Monash Motor Sport\Junior Project\Junior Project\MotionControlData.xlsx') #place "r" before the path string to address special character, such as '\'. Don't forget to put the file name at the end of the path + '.xlsx'

df_x = pd.DataFrame(data_frame, columns= ['x'])

df_y = pd.DataFrame(data_frame, columns= ['y'])

df_angle = pd.DataFrame(data_frame, columns= ['angle'])

df_vel = pd.DataFrame(data_frame, columns= ['vel'])


# Creating dataset
x = np.array(df_x)
y = np.array(df_y)
angle = np.array(df_angle)
vel = np.array(df_vel)

z = vel
 
x = np.reshape(x, (6147, 6147))
y = np.reshape(y, (6147, 6147))
z = np.reshape(z, (6147, 6147))


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

[image: Photo reference from comment section]

[image: Array of z plotted]

---

New code for new context to comments

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri May 13 18:30:41 2022

@author: alexd
"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

data_frame = pd.read_excel (r'\Users\alexd\OneDrive\Documents\University\Monash Motor Sport\Junior Project\Junior Project\MotionControlData.xlsx') #place "r" before the path string to address special character, such as '\'. Don't forget to put the file name at the end of the path + '.xlsx'

df_x = pd.DataFrame(data_frame, columns= ['x'])

df_y = pd.DataFrame(data_frame, columns= ['y'])

df_angle = pd.DataFrame(data_frame, columns= ['angle'])

df_vel = pd.DataFrame(data_frame, columns= ['vel'])


# Creating dataset
x = np.array(df_x)
y = np.array(df_y)
angle = np.array(df_angle)
vel = np.array(df_vel)

z = vel
 


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.squeeze(x), np.squeeze(y))

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z.T, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=1, antialiased=False)


ax.set_xlabel('X ')
ax.set_ylabel('Y ')
ax.set_zlabel('Velocity ')

plt.show()
```

[image: Current Graph]

[image: Variable Explorer for variables of interest]

Comment: Could you provide more clarification about the data you are trying to plot? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do or what you expect will happen. Do you need to do interpolation or something? e.g. https://www.delftstack.com/api/scipy/2d-interpolation-python/

Comment: I have an x, y co ordinate system, and at every point along a path the vehicle has a velocity. I wish to plot the velocity on the z axis against the grid of the x y co-ord system.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to do this kind of thing with [`xarray`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/index.html), because it can construct the NumPy array for you without you needing to worry about the order in which you read in the data, or the shape of the dataset.

In a nutshell, `xarray` gives you Pandas-like indexing for n-dimensional NumPy arrays (and a lot more besides). So, for instance, you can have geographic (x, y) coordinates for your 2-D NumPy array, instead of having to use NumPy's 0-based integer indices.

There are two main data structures: the `xarray.DataArray`, which is basically like a NumPy array, and the `xarray.Dataset` which is like a collection of `DataArray` objects that share coordinates.

So you'll either want to use [`xarray.DataArray.from_series`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.from_series.html) for a single variable (e.g. `angle`) or [`xarray.Dataset.from_dataframe`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.from_dataframe.html) for multiple variables (e.g. `angle` and `vel`). In each case, the dataframe's index or multi-index is used for the coordinate(s), so you'll want to set that first.

You'll want to start with something like:

```py
import xarray as xr

df = df.set_index(['x', 'y'])
ds = xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)
ds['angle'].plot()
```

Comment: This seems very helpful however from looking at https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.set_index.html, and having the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xarray' from the code provided above i am not sure how to actually go about implementing this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your data exactly are, so I cannot run a test case. However it seems a pretty standard case. Assuming `z` is indeed long enough to be reshaped into (6147, 6147), you probably need just

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.squeeze(x), np.squeeze(y))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z.T)
```

Comment: Oh cool this did something promising, is there anyway to make the image a better resolution of view it in a different angle or colour?  I will attach a photo to the orignal post

Comment: Sure, use the keyword cmap: I like cm.jet
`from matplotlib import cm`
`ax.plot_surface(x, y, z.T, cmap=cm.jet)`

Comment: two things, adding the cm=cm.jet seems to break the code and i've also realised that this is ploting the range of z i.e -10 to 6 for each position rather than just the value of interest what do you could fix this ?  UserWarning: Z contains NaN values. This may result in rendering artifacts.
  ax.plot_surface(x, y, z.T)

Comment: It's not cm=cm.jet, it's cmap=cm.jet

Comment: Sorry I miss typed, I posted the current code in the orignal post with the output

Comment: vel has not enough entries to be a function of both x and y, so I do not know how to help